# How to declare timestamp in dbeaver?

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, datetime-format, dbeaver

I created the table as per below in dbeaver

create  table warehouse
(id varchar,
onhand_quantity int,
onhand_quantitydelta int,
event_type varchar,
event_datetime timestamp
)

But still the event_datetime is declared as varchar in the table. Could someone please help. Thank you. I want to insert the format '2020-05-25 0:25' in event_datetime field

Answer (score 2):

[Java date pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

The default value for timestamp is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Following the same, insert ‘2020-05-25 0:25:00’ in the event_datetime field.

Comment: But the table structure shows that event_datetime as string